# What is the best practice for monolithic desktop frontend-backend communication?

Tags: c#, communication, desktop-application

For a monolithic desktop application with two projects - a frontend and a backend, both in C#, what would be the best practice for communication between them?

The frontend needs to make calls to the back and get progress report back. If service references are added for both projects, a circular service reference will occur, therefore this is not a valid option.

What would be the best practice to both be able for the front to make calls to the back and the back send progress reports to the front?

Editing with more details.

This is a Visual Studio 2019 solution with two projects inside it. One is a WPF project and is the frontend, the other is a console application project and is the backend. Both projects are bundled in the same .exe and work in the same process. Everything is C#. The startup project is the WPF one, while the console project is used like a library, it is a console project, instead of truly a library, so that I can change the startup project to be it and debug some code with output to the console. Since both projects are in the same solution it is easy to add a "Project reference" to the dependencies of the WPF project and call backend code but if that backend code wants to report anything to the frontend I can't do it using the same "Project reference" method, as it will cause a circular dependency.

Comment: You probably want to use an HTTP based protocol to leverage existing facilities.  Would REST calls or web sockets be an option?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, but it's a monolith, I thought to use HTTP or REST you'd have to start the backend as a service, which isn't a monolith, anymore?

Comment: "but it's a monolith" - when you say "backend", do you use it in a more loose sense? I.e., do you mean that it's a DLL that implements the business logic, with no UI - but it's all the same physical application?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, yes, it's just a console application project in the same solution. So I have a WPF project, which is my frontend and start project and another project, the said console application, the backend. You might ask "why a console application?", because when I need to work/manually check something in the backend I can just set it as the startup project and have a super easy UI, while when the frontend is the startup it behaves like a library.

Comment: Hard to say. It depends on many things. For example. Are these 2 processes a bundle? Are they executed as one in the same host? Is the backend a sort of server which holds the communication with other clients (frontends)?

Comment: It is a monolith?  So you just want to design some internal API calls?

Comment: You can either (1) treat the console app like a DLL (or maybe extract a DLL from it) and add it as a project reference, but you'll have to modify it so that you can pass something to it (some object, a function, or a lambda) from the WPF app that the console app can use for reporting back (you may need to do some refactoring first to make this possible), or (2) start the console app as a separate process and leverage the input/output of the console app itself.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović not sure, but I get the feeling that OP is asking for the "best" way to implement that "I/o" of your last option.

Comment: @Laiv Maybe. The question states "If service references are added for both projects, a circular service reference will occur"; since the question is tagged C#, I was under the impression that the OP is speaking about adding .Net project references in Visual Studio (to each other - circular dependency) - that's why I included my option (1).

Comment: @OP: Yeah - best if you edit the question to clarify some of these details (comments are volatile).

Comment: @FilipMilovanović, yes all of you are correct - I edited it.

Comment: @Laiv, I hope it is more clear now with my edit to the question.

Comment: If the work in your console application is done in a public class that it creates, you can create that class from a project reference in WPF project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For reporting back from the backend to the frontend, you can use events in C#.

In that way, the backend defines the methods that are available to make changes and the events it will fire to inform interested parties of updates. The frontend can register an event handler for those events it is interested in.

That way, you don't have a circular dependency, because the backend doesn't even know about the frontend project.

Comment: Do you mean register an event handler in the frontend for an event that occurs in the backend and use the project reference the frontend has to the backend to get the event and add the handler to it?

Comment: @Identicon, Yes, exactly that

Comment: Wait! How will the event handler be executed? As in "what thread"? I don't want my GUI to freeze up, so should I, somehow, instruct them to be run on another thread or will that be taken care of automatically?

Comment: You have to take care of the multithreading yourself. See the answer by @DocBrown.

Answer (score 2):

The most simple approach I can think of is to

- make your backend functions expect a delegate, probably of type `Action<int>`
- call this delegate inside the backend code, for example, with some percentage of the total progress
- pass a function from the frontend for this delegate parameter which can take the percentage value and visualize the achieved progress

Pseudocode

```
 void MyBackendCalculation(List<T> items,  Action<int> ShowProgress)
 {
      int n=0;
      foreach(var item in item)
      {
          ProcessItem(item);
          ShowProgress((int)(n*100.0 / item.Count));
      }
 }

 // Frontend:

   MyBackendCalculation(items,MyShowProgress);
   //...

 void MyShowProgress(int percentage)
 {
      // ... update progress bar here ...
 }
```

However, this alone can make your GUI unresponsive during the execution of a long-running backend function. Hence, you may consider to make the calls to the backend asynchronous, for example, using `async` / `await`. This, however, requires the called deletegate to use `Dispatcher.Invoke(...)`, like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15504826/invokerequired-in-wpf).

For more complex scenarios, one can also use events for this, like suggested in [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/419842). Events in C# are also based on delegates, so there is technically no huge difference, but it may require more code for a little bit more flexibility which you probably don't need.

Answer (score -1):

For a monolithic desktop application, the best way to handle the communication is to have the backend run a background task that has call back functions.

That could be the [System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=net-5.0)

Your backend code would have an function / event handler (signature of object, DoWorkEventArgs), which your front end would register and you would kick everything off by calling the background workers RunWorkerAsync method.

Or you could use define a method in your backend that returns a [Task<T>](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/)

```
async Task<T> BackEndMethodAsync(Whatever youWant
                           IProgress<int> progress,
                           CancellationToken ct)
```